(Ubuntu 24.04) How to remove systemd-hwdb
I want to remove systemd-hwdb from my computer due to it being deprecated, but I have no idea how I would go about doing this.

What leads you to believe that systemd-hwdb is deprecated? Adding a link in your question to an authoritative source would help a lot.

Perhaps you are misreading the ubuntu-drivers list output, it is hwdb that is deprecated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
